# App based on mind map to model what lies around the heart, and how to maintain it

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, user-centered-design, customer-experience, new-experience

I am using the [mind mapping](https://www.mindmaps.com/what-is-mind-mapping) software [miMind](http://mimind.cryptobees.com/), on Android, from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cryptobees.mimind&gl=US).

I want to make the following mind map, but the features are not available.

In the center of the mind map, I want to place the heart.

At the next level, for each person I love, their name.

At the next level, the things each person likes the most.

At the next level, what they like, but such that such thing they like is a little bit further away from their heart.

Eventually, a border is crossed.

After the border, there are things that, in level of dislike, are disliked by such a person.

(Of course, my heart, is confused with the ones of the people I like).

So, I want to make level curves, around the levels. Even within the likes curve.

This is because, the level curves with the closer likes, make the person, more insurmountable at a healthy heart increase level (I, don't know how to explain, this, biologically). If you choose the outer curves, you like more things, but the interoperability of the hearts of the people within the level curve is now spiked (because, there are more things to keep track of).

If you don't know what a level curve is, please see the book [*Calculus* by James Stewart](https://books.google.com/books/about/Calculus.html?id=spiaBAAAQBAJ), and look it up. But, here it is simply a closed circular surface around a group of nodes from the graph that is the mind map I am talking about.

Then, on each like, I want to be able to click on it, and edit (then, view), the give up chain (of, things, I (as a person), am willing to consider, and exchange, as things I am willing, to give up, to achieve that person's like.

In that chain, there is, closest to the goal (the person's like), the thing, that is closest to the fullness of my heart, ) and, most abundant, (in, some way).

Next in the chain, there is something less abundant (or, rather, more abundant, but that would leave mi more at an empty stomach).

Next, in the chain, there is some other thing, that I have, but would leave me fasting (if I were, to give it up).

At the end, (when you have given up everything), to achieve that person's like, you can place a fast node.

But that's not the end.

Since, there, is, more than one person, in your like graph (around your heart), you must be able to place level curves around the giveup graphs (with, rationing).

This can, or, perhaps, should, be done, by considering each level curve as a node, with the contents of each node surrounded by a giveup node, with rationing.

We can see where this is going. This could be used for both your girlfriends, boyfriends, or for your customers.

It would be a nice app, and we don't have it in the list.

Can anyone suggest improvements to this design, or implement a prototype, perhaps with examples from their own personal life with pictures of girlfriends boyfriends (shaded out or mocked for privacy), and a list of supermarket or otherb material or work object giveup items.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a complex and very specific design problem that can only really be solved by you. You are clearly the Subject Matter Expert in this case as well as the expert in this unusual mapping system. I don't think there's anyone here who can help you and I'm not sure where to redirect you for better help with this.

Comment: Can you add an example drawing to your question?

Comment: Have you made some progress with this concept? It would be interesting to see what you have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like an interesting idea for an app, and the only thing I can think of that is designed to model things in such a way might be an interface similar to the open graph application [System](https://about.system.com/product/system) that is designed to map and manage complex knowledge and information. But it doesn't include the level curve that you mentioned, because it is a more generic application that can be used to map any type of information.

I suggest that you come up with a wireframe or mockup to help clarify and maybe simplify the interface design because it is going to be easier to increase complexity from a simple design compared to trying to simplify the interface if the underlying concepts are too complex.

You can also look at ideas for complex graph interfaces that are used in game engine design like Unreal Engine that has inputs and outputs connected in different ways.